# Keep running container (dev-container) if there is a error?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, vscode-devcontainer

I'm currently developing in an Odoo container , but every time the main process terminates and I have VSCODE attached I need to reload to make it connect again.

To prevent this, inside .devcontainermodify the file `docker-compose.yml` with the following line:

```
#....more configs
# Overrides default command so things don't shut down after the process ends.
command: /bin/sh -c "while sleep 1000; do :; done"
```

This is my devcontainer.json:

```json
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.245.2/containers/docker-existing-docker-compose
// If you want to run as a non-root user in the container, see .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml.
{
        "name": "Existing Docker Compose (Extend)",

        // Update the 'dockerComposeFile' list if you have more compose files or use different names.
        // The .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml file contains any overrides you need/want to make.
        "dockerComposeFile": [
                "../docker-compose.yml",
                "docker-compose.yml"
        ],

        // The 'service' property is the name of the service for the container that VS Code should
        // use. Update this value and .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml to the real service name.
        "service": "web",

        // The optional 'workspaceFolder' property is the path VS Code should open by default when
        // connected. This is typically a file mount in .devcontainer/docker-compose.yml
        "workspaceFolder": "/home",

        // Use 'forwardPorts' to make a list of ports inside the container available locally.
        // "forwardPorts": [],

        // Uncomment the next line if you want start specific services in your Docker Compose config.
        // "runServices": [],

        // Uncomment the next line if you want to keep your containers running after VS Code shuts down.
        // "shutdownAction": "none",

        // Uncomment the next line to run commands after the container is created - for example installing curl.
        // "postCreateCommand": "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl",

        // Uncomment to connect as a non-root user if you've added one. See https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
        "remoteUser": "root"
}
```

Even with everything, when I get an error, I have to raise the container again docker-compose up, which causes VSCODE to disconnect.

Inside the container I use a config option that restarts the service every time it detects a code change, similar to the function nodemon in nodejs, but unlike nodemon, if a fatal "uncompilable" error occurs the service stops completely and exits with an error code.

How can I avoid this behavior? Is there a way to ignore the error code so I don't have to reload vscode?

## UPDATE

This is an example of my docker compose file:

```yaml
version: '3.1'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:14.0
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    volumes:
      - odoo-web-data:/var/lib/odoo
      - ./config:/etc/odoo
      - ./addons:/mnt/extra-addons
    environment:
      - PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_password
    secrets:
      - postgresql_password
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/postgresql_password
      - POSTGRES_USER=odoo
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    volumes:
      - odoo-db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
    secrets:
      - postgresql_password
volumes:
  odoo-web-data:
  odoo-db-data:

secrets:
  postgresql_password:
    file: odoo_pg_pass
```

[Odoo Image](https://hub.docker.com/_/odoo)

Comment: How did you start devcontainer? You don't need to run `docker-compose up` to start the devcontainer.

Comment: Since I use docker compose and I need to see the logs, I first run docker-compose up, and then use the "reopen in container" option and all is well. The problem is that when the service inside docker gets stuck, I have to restart vscode because the container goes offline.

Comment: Regardless of Vscode, when you container is up, did you try to change the codes and throw a error to see if the container is down? If so, this is not a related vscode issue, you should find a way keep the container to run if there is a error.

Comment: @ikhvjs That's exactly what I was trying to say. I already changed the title of my question.

Comment: Maybe share your docker image as a example for reference?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tty: `true`, where `bash` will be able to create interactive session and the container will be started

```yaml
#docker-compose.yml
services:
  container-name:
    image: $IMAGE
...
    tty: true # docker run -t
...
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground

> In foreground mode (the default when -d is not specified), docker run
> can start the process in the container and attach the console to the
> process’s standard input, output, and standard error. It can even
> pretend to be a TTY (this is what most command line executables
> expect) and pass along signals.